# Returning a value of a function does not work over multiple iterations via for loop

Tags: python, return

I defined the following function:

```
def test():
    return 1
```

And once I type the following in the console:

```
test()
```

I get the expected value of 1 returned. But I want to 1 to be returned twice, so I type this in the console:

```
values = [1,2]
for i in values:
    test()
```

But instead I get no output now. Why does it not produce any output and how could I edit it so it would?

Comment: `print(test())`? If you're working in a REPL like the interpreter, output is only shown for expressions or explicit `print`s.

Comment: In the first case the REPL print the return value of 1, in the second, case the block of code returns Nothing and thus nothing is printed

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should fix your for loop. If you want to specify the number of times a for loop should run, you should use range() function.

```
for x in range(2):
    test()
```

and second, return value doesn't output the values unless you print it, i.e `print(test())`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to print the returned value to display it in console. Try this:

```py
values = [1, 2]
for i in values:
    print(test())
```

You might ask why did it work in first case. I don't have the exact answer but I can give you a clue. Returned value of "last line of code" is automatically printed. This is not the right/good explanation. Maybe someone else can help with this.

Btw, here's a better way of writing the above piece of code:

```py
for i in range(2):
    print(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

just put a print on test() inside the for loop, like below

```
for i in values:
    print(test())
```

Now output would be:

```
   1
   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but when I run this code on my computer, everything is fine

```
def test():
    return 1

print("First case:")
print(test())

print("Second case:")
list = [1,2]
for i in list:
    print(test())
```

OUTPUT:

```
First case:
1
Second case:
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, doing a `print` inside the loop will print the value.  The subtlety that nobody else has mentioned is that the *reason* the for loop doesn't work on its own is that a `for` doesn't return a value.  The expressions inside of the loop are evaluated but their values are discarded.

If you want to do a loop that *does* return the value of the expressions inside it (so that you can see those values in the interpreter without having to print them, or do something else with those values in the next part of your program), a list comprehension is a good way:

```
>>> def test():
...     return 1
...
>>> values = [1,2]
>>> [test() for i in values]
[1, 1]
```